# moving data between pages in angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to pass data between two components, but I'm having some issue with it.  When the new component (page) loads, I lose the data I passed into my service.  Here's what I've got:

```
// store-data.service.ts
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
@Injectable()
export class StoreDataService {
    private storedData: any;
}
```

-

```
// search.component.ts
import {Component, Input, OnInit}   from '@angular/core';
import {Router}                     from "@angular/router";
import {SearchService}              from "./search.service.ts";
import {StoreDataService}           from "./store-data.service.ts";

@Component({
    selector: 'search',
    templateUrl: 'search.component.html',
    providers: [ SearchService, StoreDataService ]
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

    resDisplay: [{ id: number, name: string, books: string[] }] = [];

    constructor( private searchService: SearchService,
               private storeDataService: StoreDataService ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.searchService.getResults(searchValue)
            .subscribe(res => { this.resDisplay = res; });
    }

    clickRes(id:number) {
        let choice = this.resData.filter(res => res === id);
        this.storeDataService.storedData = choice[0];
        this.router.navigate(['detail-page'];
    }
}
```

-

```
// page-detail.component.ts
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core'
import {ActivatedRoute}   from '@angular/router'
import {StoreDataService} from "../../core/store-data/store-data.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'detail-page',
    templateUrl: 'detail.component.html',
    providers: [ DetailSearchService, StoreDataService ]
})
export class PageDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    detils: MoreDetails;

    constructor(private detailSearchService: DetailSearchService,
                private storeDataService: StoreDataService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
       console.log(this.storeDataService.storedData);

       /* do stuff utilizing the storedData 
        * and get more infor from the detailSearchService. 
        */
    }
}
```

I can see the storedData receiving the value from the SearchPage. But when I try to spit it out on the DetailPage, it is undefined.

I also tried implementing the StoreDataService using Observables, with the same result on the detailPage.

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Note: any misspellings are immaterial. When I get a bit more time, I'll try to provide a plunker example.

Comment: `private storedData: any;` is that misspelling or your real code? Typescript should throw error when you try to  write to private property

Comment: Its obvious. Both the components get injected with the different instance of  StoreDataService so that won't persist the data in your storedData variable.

Comment: You should only get the data you required on Search component and pass the Id to the PageDetail component where you will pull up the complete information about that object.

Comment: @A.Tim Oops. I was starting to write my observable implementation, then changed my mind about it. I forgot to remove it.

Comment: @AliBaig That was my first thought, but I asked around and was told that it was a Singleton. But obviously that's not the case as given by the answer below and my experience.  Also, if I pass just the ID, there is a value that can only be known from the search page that will be lost on the detail page.  "If search by email, display that email address in a certain field. If search by phone, display that phone number in the field." By only providing the id, I won't know the correct email or phone number to display in that field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you provide the service inside the `@Component`,

```
@Component({
    selector: 'search',
    templateUrl: 'search.component.html',
    providers: [ SearchService, StoreDataService ]<-- new instance
})
```

That service will have a new instance. If you want to have a singleton instance of this service among your components that are in the same module, define it inside the module (`@NgModule`). If they are not in the same module then create a shared module and define it there.